# Error on Display Estimated Execution Plan with window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I just wanted to have a look how the execution plan of a query changes, when i add window functions like LAG().

But, when i add a window function to my query like LAG() & click on "Display Estimated Execution Plan" it returns me following error.

```
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Error processing execution plan results. The error message is:
There is an error in XML document (1, 12308).
Instance validation error: 'Window Spool' is not a valid value for PhysicalOpType.
```

SQL Server:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) 
13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) 
on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

I never experienced this behavior before. Any ideas why the execution plan can't be estimated?

Comment: Help -> About. What version is Management Studio? The latest versions are [deployed independently from SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), so no reason not to be up-to-date.

Comment: Are you using an older version of the toolset?  Seems like that could cause the validation error.  If the server is 2016, install the 2016 SSMS tools.  Here's a related thread where that appears to be the answer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05869260-f6a7-44a6-b2ab-da638e050ec2/instance-validation-error-window-spool-is-not-a-valid-value-for-physicaloptype?forum=transactsql

Comment: thats it! I just figured out i have been running on a client with SQL Management Studio 2008. As window functions were added later with SQL Server 2012, the "older" version of Mgmt Studio is of course not able to show the plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: 
Version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is older than Microsoft SQL Server itself.

In my case: 
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Version 10.50.1600.1 (for SQL Server 2008 R2)
Microsoft SQL Server 2016

As windowed functions like LAG() have been released with SQL Server 2012, the older Management Studio version is not able to interpret/display the execution plan with windowed functions.

Comment: It's best to use the separate downloadable SSMS version going forward. This is kept up-to-date for new SQL versions, including Azure SQL Database and includes some support for versions yet to be released (SQL 2017). Current version as of this writing is SSMS 17.1.

Comment: i know. just a little complicated over here. i have to use the workstation of a customer within a project and not able to install anything. but i'll try to convince them.